# ORI Research Misconduct rulemaking comments

Tags: research-misconduct, policy, irb

I am writing comments on the Public Health Service Policies on Research Misconduct on regulations.gov. This is my first time making comments on policy making. I am curious if HHS ever censors these comments if they are embarrassing to OHRP. I openly criticize them and explain in pretty good detail why. I've tried talking to OHRP since June and they won't have a conversation with me because, as they cite, the policies they created allow them to turn a blind eye to QI/research misconduct not funded by the government even if it is at an institution the government is giving money to. I submitted my complaint twice. Both dismissed. I've experience retaliation and further misconduct by the hospital that is really alarming! Someone outside the IRB responded to part of my IRB complaint at the hospital, in an official capacity, in the most startling and ironic way they could have during this particular investigation into one of the co-authors. So I've emailed OHRP countless times and get replies with one or two sentences with no human signature. So no accountability. The institution I made my complaint about gets tens of millions in research funding annually. they have a $190 million research portfolio. There are over a thousand clinical trials going on and recruiting participants. But if you go to the IRB website and click on the link to email them a complaint, the email bounces back. This has been happening since Feb. 2023 at least. My complaint wasn't received at all when I first sent it. I had to make several calls and speak with three people to get my complaint heard and was then given an email where I sent a written complaint. But the main IRB email link is to an incorrect email that bounces back. And this is wild to me. I'm not sure where to find FWA rules about this, **but someone please tell me this isn't acceptable according to FWA rules**. This reading is so difficult for me and I spend day and night trying to answer my questions. It's weird because they already investigated one of these guys before. And they are still totally disinterested. Almost like they are more interested in protecting him than me. It's all very odd and troubling. Because this one guy is really famous. And my complaint is pretty extensive, backed completely by evidence, and OHRP is blatantly not answering my questions or addressing my concerns in any sort of way that resembles appropriate.

Essentially, the point I am making to Director Garrity is that HHS should not move forward with any changes to the policy to alleviate administrative and financial burdens of researchers and institutions until the consequences of the Revised Common Rule are systematically investigated. Specifically, the appropriateness of OHRPs responses to participants harmed by the Revised Common Rule, prioritizing institutions and researchers over research participants and participants whose right to informed consent were waived, should be thoroughly examined before making additional changes that could further damage research integrity.

I don't cuss in my comments. I think I'm respectful, but I am a bit of an asshat with my honesty. I am unafraid to share the most embarrassing details because (of therapy) and because I think those details make the point I am trying to make. The harm the did to me is embarrassing, to me, to the hospital, to the researchers, to the government. I want my comments public, but I call out OHRP essentially for ignoring my emails and complaints despite retaliation and misconduct after the IRB investigation has begun in several ways. I've asked so many times for guidance and they won't even respond to me at this point.

Do I have to not be an asshat at all for my comments to get posted? Does anyone have any relevant experience? I'm not really a professional here. I don't really do things very professionally. But I'm hoping I don't have to. Has anyone encountered comments that were perhaps close to crossing some line of appropriateness? Or any other thoughts anyone?

Thank you.

Comment: Government agencies are bound by laws. It seems you are upset with a law. You can't change the law by complaining to the government agency, they do not have the power to change law through rulemaking. If you think the law is bad you can ask lawmakers to change it. If you think you've been harmed you should discuss with a lawyer who can assess the legal merits of your case.

Comment: I don't think you understood my post at all. The government is asking for comments on policy. I am responding saying they should not make changes to that policy for institutions' administrative and financial burdens. I am just saying it in a very sassy way. I am so tongue in cheek. I do not know if they will actually post it. And OHRP accepts complaints about human subject research and IRBs. That is literally their job to accept complaints. It sounds like you don't understand these government agencies and rule making. I don't need a lawyer. I need the government to do their job.

Comment: I don't think this is the place for this question but if you want your comment to be taken seriously, I assume it should be professional and well thought-out.